# PHP error when passing an array

Tags: php, arrays

got an problem I am trying to resolve.  I have the following

```
$inputParams = array();

//fill up array

if (!empty($inputParams)) {
    $controller = new ConnectionService();
    $response = call_user_func_array(array($controller, "obtainToken"), $inputParams);
    var_dump($inputParams);
}
```

Now in the above var_dump, the output is something like

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "myemail@gmail.com" [1]=> string(13) "+44776587535" }
```

So it clearly outputs an array.  You also see that I pass the array to a function in the `call_user_func_array` call.  This array is passed to my `ConnectionService` class, the function `obtainToken`.

Now the above method does some work (not with the array) and then passes the array to another function

```
public function obtainToken($inputParams)
{
    //other stuff

    try{
        $this->insertData($inputParams);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

And then the last function for the array

```
public function insertData($inputParams)
{
    var_dump($inputParams);

    try{
        //some stuff
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I then `var_dump` the array again, but this time I get

```
string(24) "myemail@gmail.com"
```

So how has my array turned from an array into a string?

Thanks

Comment: My money's on either `some stuff` or `other stuff`.

Comment: You are only 'capturing" a single parameter in your method while you are passing two (because the array has two elements). Either accept 2 params in the method or use `call_user_func` if you want a single parameter (array)

Comment: obtainToken never got the array, only the first element of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encapsulate your $inputParams argument into an array so that the first argument pass to obtainToken is the $inputParams array.

```
 $response = call_user_func_array(array($controller, "obtainToken"), array($inputParams));
```

Comment: thats worked, thanks.  Is there any reason it has to be encapsulated?  It is an array in the first place, and when I checked the docs this parameter expected an array (which it was).

Comment: the second argument for the call_user_func is an array of arguments. hence when you pass $inputParams, it actually pass 2 arguments which is $inputParams[0] and $inputParams[1]. by encapsulating, you're passing the first element of the array[0] which contains $inputParams array.